# Apache2 server very slow download speed

Tags: 18.04, apache2, webserver

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.2 with a LAMP stack installed

The VPS running it has 16GB RAM and 6 CPU@2.2GHz, with 400Mb/s bandwidth provided, so this definitely shouldn't be maxing it out. It's also only used as the file download location of my site, downloads.example.com. Not seeing heavy usage either

The device being used to download the files is running on LTE with 7-8 MBps (megabyte not bit) internet

However, downloading a ~100MB file with either wget or curl is averaging 70KB/s

What's the issue here, and how do I solve it?

Comment: Where is the server hosted? Where are you located? Could you give us a file to test? Have you tested from multiple locations?

Comment: @vidarlo server hosted in Germany I'm in USA. Tested before with ftp transfer, and Speedtest on the server never showed below 100Mb/s

Comment: Then the problem is probably related to either bad peering agreements (you're a far way away from the server) or TCP window scaling. TCP to a certain extent waits for acknowledgement before putting more data on the wire. This causes a problem on high latency and/or high bandwidth. Test it from Europe, and check speed then.

Comment: @vidarlo I can't exactly just go to Europe :-) so how do you recommend I test it?

Comment: Ask someone in Europe to test it for you, for instance by posting a link to a large file here, or get an instance in some cloud service, e.g. Google Cloud or AWS for an hour to test it. Firing up a instance for half an hour in AWS or Google Cloud is free if you're new customer, and will cost a few cents if you're not.